# while maintaining the Realm in the list - all the values in it the same

Tags: swift, list, realm

I I have two data models and want to fill them with values from the loaded my json code, it has an array of unique enter values. But after saving in the Realm I get an array of the same mean (equal to the last value in the original array).

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Data: Object {
    dynamic var city_n: String = ""
    var templst = List<temp>()
    dynamic var update_d = NSDate()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "city_n"
    }
}
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class temp: Object {
        dynamic var t: String = ""
}
```

And a function that fills them

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL , parameters: param)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                        case .Success:
                            if let value = response.result.value {
                                let json = JSON(value)
                                onlineLW.city_n = json["city"]["name"].stringValue
                                onlineLW.update_d = NSDate()
                                var temp_arr: [String] = []
                                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["list"] {
                                    ot.t = subJson["main"]["temp"].stringValue
                                    onlineLW.templst.append(ot)
                                    temp_arr.append(subJson["main"]["temp"].stringValue)
                                }
                                for var i = 1; i < temp_arr.count; i++ {
                                    onlineLW.templst[i].t = temp_arr[i]
                                    print("onlineLW.templst[i].t = \(onlineLW.templst[i].t)")
                                    print("temp_arr[i] = \(temp_arr[i])")
//                                    onlineLW.templst.append(ot)
                                }

                               print(onlineLW.templst)
                                try! self.realm.write {
                                    self.realm.add(onlineLW, update: true)
                                }
                               load.flag = true
                        }
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                    }
```

The output is a list of identical elements. What's the problem could be? Thank you.

Execute Results:

```
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 279.59
temp_arr[i] = 279.59
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.13
temp_arr[i] = 278.13
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 275.09
temp_arr[i] = 275.09
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 272.77
temp_arr[i] = 272.77
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 275.26
temp_arr[i] = 275.26
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.3
temp_arr[i] = 278.3
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 281.9
temp_arr[i] = 281.9
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 282.85
temp_arr[i] = 282.85
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 282.39
temp_arr[i] = 282.39
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 277.75
temp_arr[i] = 277.75
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.42
temp_arr[i] = 278.42
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 276.82
temp_arr[i] = 276.82
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.82
temp_arr[i] = 278.82
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.55
temp_arr[i] = 278.55
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 278.94
temp_arr[i] = 278.94
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 280.73
temp_arr[i] = 280.73
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 279.79
temp_arr[i] = 279.79
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 277.639
temp_arr[i] = 277.639
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 276.363
temp_arr[i] = 276.363
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 274.554
temp_arr[i] = 274.554
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 274.191
temp_arr[i] = 274.191
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 273.961
temp_arr[i] = 273.961
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 273.637
temp_arr[i] = 273.637
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 276.294
temp_arr[i] = 276.294
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 277.662
temp_arr[i] = 277.662
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 275.412
temp_arr[i] = 275.412
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 273.323
temp_arr[i] = 273.323
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 272.665
temp_arr[i] = 272.665
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 272.789
temp_arr[i] = 272.789
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 272.563
temp_arr[i] = 272.563
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 274.97
temp_arr[i] = 274.97
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 279.417
temp_arr[i] = 279.417
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 279.376
temp_arr[i] = 279.376
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 276.51
temp_arr[i] = 276.51
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 273.889
temp_arr[i] = 273.889
onlineLW.templst[i].t = 271.158
temp_arr[i] = 271.158
Data {
    city_n = Paris;
    update_d = 2016-02-12 09:27:31 +0000;
    templst = List<temp> (
        [0] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [1] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [2] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [3] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [4] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [5] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [6] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [7] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [8] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [9] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [10] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [11] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [12] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [13] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [14] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [15] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [16] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [17] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [18] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [19] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [20] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [21] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [22] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [23] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [24] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [25] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [26] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [27] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [28] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [29] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [30] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [31] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [32] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [33] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [34] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [35] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        },
        [36] temp {
            t = 271.158;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are appending `ot` to your list in every iteration of your first for loop. Since `ot` is a reference type (it is a Class in this particular case) when you change its `t` value in the next iteration it changes all the previously appended values of `t`. To solve this I would change your first for loop like this:

```
for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["list"] {
    let newOt = temp()
    newOt.t = subJson["main"]["temp"].stringValue
    onlineLW.templst.append(newOt)
    temp_arr.append(subJson["main"]["temp"].stringValue)
}
```

Above for loop creates a new `temp` in every iteration and appends it to your list, so this should solve your problem. If this solves this problem you can even remove your second for loop completely and also remove the `temp_arr`. Hope his helps.